# Correctly Using Header Files?

Tags: c, file, header

Lately I have been using header files to split up my program into separate files, (C files containing functions and header files declaring them). Every thing works fine but for some reason, I need to include `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` in EVERY C file... or my project fails to compile. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: well, they are quite common to include… but surely not required everywhere. assert and stdint are the ones i find i need most often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C modules need to know either how something is defined, or where it can find a definition. If the definition is in the header file, then you should include it in the modules that use it. Here is a [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html) to information regarding header files.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would depend on whether or not that functions might depend on other declared functions in other .c/.h files.

For example:

`filea.c`:

```
#include "filea.h";

    methodA()
    {
        methodB();
    }
```

`fileb.c`:

```
#include <somelibrary.h>
#include "fileb.h"


    methodB();
    {
        somelibrarycode();
    }
```

This will not compile unless `filea.c` includes the header for `fileb.h` as it has some external dependency that is not resolved.

If this is not what you're describing than there is some other spaghettification happening, or you accidentally statically typed functions preventing them from being seen outside of the `.c` file.

One possible solution to this problem is to have a single `shared.h` with all the other includes, but I personally don't recommend this as this merely masks the issue instead of making it readily apparently which files depend on what and establish clear lines of dependency.

Comment: This isn't quite my problem but did give me some insight thank you the link provided in the answer I accepted helped a lot though!

Answer (score 0):

They must be included *some* way.

Some projects require long list of includes in .c files, possibly with mandatory sort, even forcing assumption that no header includes any other header.

Some allow assuming some includes form some headers.

Some use collection headers (that include a list of small headers) and replace long lists with those.

Some go even further, using "forced header" option of compiler, so include will not appear anywhere, and declare the content to be implicitly assumed.  It may go on project or whole codebase level, or combined. It plays pretty well with precompiled headers.

(And there are many more strategies, you get the figure, all with some pros&cons.)