# c++ accessing functions from another file

Tags: c++, private, public, sharing

I'm learning c++ and having a bit of trouble with how you share methods with different files and or classes.

if I make a function called increment(int a){a++;  return a;}

and have it defined in a.cpp how would I call it in main.cpp?
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943457/correctly-using-header-files

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch +1. There is even  a [list of good books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) here on SO.

Comment: Also enable all warnings and debugging info. On Linux, compile with `g++ -Wall -g` and learn to use the `gdb` debugger.

Answer (score 6):

1. Put `int increment(int a);` at the top of *main.cpp*.
2. Compile both files into object files (with g++, you can use the `-c` option for that).
3. Link both files together (with g++, just say `g++ main.o increment.o -o increment.exe`).

Now, declaring `int increment(int a);` in every *cpp*-file that uses this function is very cumbersome. That's why a shortcut exists:

1. Create a file *increment.h* with the single line `int increment(int a);`
2. Put `#include "increment.h"` at the top of *main.cpp*.

Problem with this method is, that *increment.h* might be included multiple times into a single *cpp*-file. This is where [*include guards*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) come in.

Answer (score 0):

Use declaration

```
 int increment(int a);
```

in the file that wants to call. Usually you #include those declarations form a common file (header) shared by many .cpp files.